# Responsive HTML table cut on mobil

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

In a Bootstrap-Modal i have a some Divs and a Table. 
When Browsing on Desktop everything works fine, but when i open the website on my phone much of the table is cut off.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal portfolio-modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content table-responsive">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            X
        </div>
        <div class="container eventContainer table-responsive">
            <div class="row tableScroll table-responsive">
                <div class="col-lg-12 tableScroll table-responsive">
                    <div class="modal-body tableScroll table-responsive">
                        <div class="eventTableDiv tableScroll table-responsive" id="eventTableDiv">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    table,
    .eventContainer,
    .eventTable,
    .tableScroll,
    .modal,
    .modal-content,
    .row,
    .modal-body{
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .eventTable {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

And the JS I use to render the table:

```
function generateEventList(){
var htmlString = "<label class='eventLabel'>Events</label><br><table class='eventTable tableScroll'><tr class='tableHeader'><th>When</th><th>Concert Hall</th><th>Event</th><th>Programm</th><th>Ensemble</th   ></tr>";
var arrayLength = eventListe.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    htmlString = htmlString.concat("<tr class='tableRow'>");
    for (var s = 0; s<5; s++) {
        htmlString = htmlString.concat("<td class='tableData'>"+eventListe[i][s]+"</td>");
    }
    htmlString = htmlString.concat("</tr>");
}
htmlString=htmlString.concat("</table><br><br>");
document.getElementById("eventTableDiv").innerHTML = htmlString;
}
```

I tried everything I could find on SO and elsewhere.

The Website can be found  [here](http://frankaherwig.de).

Its the first modal called 'Schedule'

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at your website, you need to rethink your table in terms of mobile users. It is difficult to display a table this wide on a mobile device.

You can try these:

1) Drastically reduce the font-size
2) Reduce the padding in the table
3) Check minimum width is not set for table columns
4) Restructure the table to display vertically
5) Use javascript or jquery to hide the overflow unless the user clicks for more

I would try it in this order.

Comment: This is done very well on tychomusic.com, where the tour dates are listed. The table is initially wide, but when shrunk down, all of the content still fits on one line. How is this accomplished?